# How to build file-name for File.WriteAllText dynamically with random number in it?

Tags: c#

I have numerous files and I want to write at a file randomly, what I want to do is this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new Stringbuilder(); 
int x;
Random rnd = new Random();

 x = rnd.Next(1,10);

File.WriteAllText("C:\\Top Folder\\File Folder\\file{0}.dat",x.ToString(),sb.ToString());
```

I know the argument on that `WriteAllText` is wrong, but that is the idea of what I want to do; Put whatever random number that is generated into `{0}` then write the contents of the `Stringbuilder` inside the file.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string file = string.Format("C:\\Top Folder\\File Folder\\file{0}.dat", x);
File.WriteAllText(file, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks a million Tim Schmelter for helping a noob :D